# Prove that $Q_n$ is k-factorabale if and only if k|n.

Tags: graph-theory

i know $Q_n$ is 1-factor but i can not solve this statement

1-Prove that $Q_n$ is k-factorabale  if and only if k|n.
2-Why $Q_n$ is a bipartite graph?

where $Q_n$ is k-qubic graph , $Q_1=K_2$ and $Q_n=K_2.Q_{n-1}$

Comment: What is $Q_n$??

Comment: What is $k$-factorable?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A $k$-factorisation of a graph is a decomposition into edge-disjoint $k$-regular graphs. For one to exist, $k$ must divide all vertex degrees.
In $Q_n$ each vertex has degree $n$.

Conversely, $Q_n$ has an obvious $1$-factorisation. If $k\mid n$
then we can construct a $k$-factorisation by joining together bunches of
$k$ $1$-factors.

We can label the vertices of $Q_n$ by $n$-tuples of zeroes and ones.
Dividing them according to the parity of the sum of the coordinates
gives a bipartition.